Turning software compiled from source to app
I have a laptop with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installed and I'm trying to replace the default Rhythmbox (version 3.4.7) with the latest version (3.4.8, not available before long in the official PPA according to the information I found on the internet). I don't want to use Flatpak for now and I'm also interested in learning "how the sausage is made" for once.
I've successfully followed the install procedure from the Rhythmbox GitLab. I can now launch Rhythmbox from the install directory with the commands:
$ export GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=$PWD/_install/share/glib-2.0/schemas
$ _install/bin/rhythmbox

My question is: What would be the correct way forward to turn this into a standard-behaving app? Basically, I want it to behave like the default version of Rhythmbox, with a launcher and such.
My (uneducated) guess would be:

Move the compilation result to the default app location (something like usr/bin)
Make a launching script (see two lines above)
Create a launcher with a shortcut (something like this)

What would be the correct way to do this?

So basically you want to create a Debian package - that's the way how applications on Ubuntu are installed. Google for "creating Debian package", you should get a lot of information, including official Debian documentation.

Isn't it a little bit overkill as I don't intend to redistribute it?

checkinstall might work for you

Would you care to elaborate a little bit more? I understand that checkinstall replaces make install but the install procedure of Rhythmbox uses meson and ninja instead. Would checkinstall work in this case?

You are correct. Unless you want to create a deb package which will properly place all the launchers, you can follow the procedure below.
Create a launching script with the following content
GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR=$PWD/_install/share/glib-2.0/schemas /path/to/_install/bin/rhythmbox

Save it as $HOME/.local/bin/rhythmbox
Create a .desktop file, and point it to run your launching script $HOME/.local/bin/rhythmbox.

Thank you. And what about copying _install/bin/rhythmbox to usr/bin/rhythmbox? Wouldn't it be the "standard" directory for an app?

That is not necessary. But you can keep it wherever you want

And just out of curiosity, what's the advantage of putting the script under $HOME/.local/bin/rhythmbox instead of the install directory?

@el_grezeq $HOME/.local/bin is equivalent to /usr/bin, but it will not conflict with any official packages. Suppose another user wants to install rhythmbox from official repo, it will conflict with your script, and there will be installation errors (the same this may happen if you try to upgrade Ubuntu in future). On the contrary, nothing like that will happen if it resides in the home folder
